# Can I free up space on my iPhone 3GS taken by application data?

Tags: ios, iphone

I click general> usage> under storage I see apps with memory usage, how do I delete these to free up space to increase available memory?

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone's home screen, tap and hold on the app you would like to delete. An "x" will appear and the icons will begin to wiggle. Tap the "x", and accept the prompt to delete the app.

Answer (score 0):

Or from Settings > General > Usage, tap on an app, then tap on Delete App.